# Getting empty list after initialization

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner with Python and I have a problem with the classes of my project. So the structure is as follows:

main.py (Firstly, main creates world instance)

```
from world import World

world = World()
```

World knows everything about all other classes (imports everything as needed) and initializes previously empty lists from inherited class PersonAttributes (where "global" variables are stored so that all classes can access them) with content.

PersonAttributes

```
class PersonAttributes:

    MALE_NAMES = []
    FEMALE_NAMES = []
    SURNAMES = []
    PROFESSIONS = []

    BABY = None
    CHILD = None
    TEEN = None
    YOUNGADULT = None
    ADULT = None
    SENIOR = None
    LIFESTAGES = (BABY, CHILD, TEEN, YOUNGADULT, ADULT, SENIOR)
```

World

```
from utilities.person_attributes import PersonAttributes
from life_stage import Baby, Child, Teen, YoungAdult, Adult, Senior

class World(PersonAttributes):

    def __init__(self):

        # Initialize names from files
        self.MALE_NAMES = self.get_male_names()
        self.FEMALE_NAMES = self.get_female_names()
        self.SURNAMES = self.get_surnames()
        self.PROFESSIONS = self.get_professions()

        # Initialize life stages
        self.BABY = Baby(None, None, None, None)
        self.CHILD = Child(None, None, None, None)
        self.TEEN = Teen(None, None, None, None)
        self.YOUNGADULT = YoungAdult(None, None, None, None)
        self.ADULT = Adult(None, None, None, None)
        self.SENIOR = Senior(None, None, None, None)

        self.population = []
        self.populate_world()
```

World also imports LifeStage class which contain different classes that inherit from Person. Example of YoungAdult (where the problem is)

```
class YoungAdult(Person):

    def __init__()

        self.occupation = Randomizer().get_random_list_item(self.PROFESSIONS)
```

person

```
from utilities.person_attributes import PersonAttributes

class Person(PersonAttributes):

    def __init__():
        super(Person, self).__init__()
```

So the problem is self.PROFESSIONS. I have initialized it in world, but then when I instantiate YoungAdult, (self.YOUNGADULT = YoungAdult(None, None, None, None)), the PROFESSIONS list from PersonAttributes is empty. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? I can't get rid of the self.occupation attribute as it is required for the YoungAdult class to automatically have a profession when person ages up from Teen. I hope you guys can understand what I mean, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you minimise the example to only the attributes relevant to the question? We shouldn't need to wade through dozens of unrelated things to understand your issue.

Comment: you should use simple module globals for most of what you seem to do with classes here.

Comment: Shouldn't you initialize your PersonAttributes class?

Comment: @deceze sorry I think everything I've written is relevant in some way? except for the constructor arguments for person! i mean so you guys could understand, but idk.

Comment: @hop global variables are generally bad design, right? what do you mean?

Comment: @Ivy I want all classes to be able to access PersonAttributes though, that's why I don't want a specific object otherwise I'd need to keep passing it between classes so they have access to the "global" variables. Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: It's easier to digest a problem when it can fit on the same page without scrolling, and when you don't have to mentally skip over things unrelated to the problem. We don't need all those different attributes, a representative sample or two will do. This is about making your question as readable and understandable as possible.

Comment: @deceaze you're right, sorry I'm gonna edit the OP and get rid of the constructors

Comment: @Koby (module) globals are not necessarily as sign of bad design, no. You seem to have a few misconceptions about Python, though, that we will possibly not be able to rectify on Stack Overflow. For example, many Python programmers tend to avoid class inheritance as much as possible (`PersonAttributes` seems to server no purpose, for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is simply a differece between class and instance attributes. This might shed some light:

```
>>> class K:
...     a = 1
...     def set_a(self, v):
...         self.a = v
... 
>>> k = K()
>>> K.a
1
>>> k.a
1
>>> k.set_a(3)
>>> k.a
3
>>> K.a
1
>>> K.a = 5
>>> l = K()
>>> l.a
5
>>> k.a
3
```

As soon as you set `k.a` (even via `self.a`) it shadows `K.a`.

Comment: this does help understand things thanks you! So what solution is there to make those "global" variables unchangeable/static after I set them with content in World? I want all classes to be able to see the filled lists, not empty ones, so that YoungAdult can automatically have a profession every time it is created, for example. I can see now that just inheriting the class makes no difference :S

Comment: From what I can see, none of this code seems necessary, thus if you were to remove it, your problems would go away as well. Try to work with simple lists of strings for a start. It's hard to tell from the limited amount code you have given, though.

Comment: I ended up changing my project structure completely and now it works, but thank you for helping me have better understanding of it!